# Dragging a subview of a view to its parent view

Tags: ios, iphone, drag-and-drop

I've been searching for the solution for hours. While I can find similar questions, I didn't get the answer. Please help me with this. Here is the situation.

I'm developing an iPad application. I have a custom UIControl (subclass of UIControl) object C within a UIScrollView B which is within the root view A. So the parent-child relationship is like this: A -> B -> C. What I want to do is to drag my custom UIControl C to the root view A. Here is what I did.

Because C is a UIControl, I registered *UIControlEventTouchDown* and *UIControlEventTouchDragInside* events to it to track the finger movement. However, the registered methods got triggered only inside C's frame. When my finger touches inside the frame, it works. When I drag it outside C's frame to B and then A, I lost the finger movement event. I wonder what's the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

The UIControlEventTouchDragInside will only notice a drag event inside the bounds of the View.  You need to also add a UIControlEventTouchDragOutside to the C View, or you can be notified of all touches and find out where the touch is on the X,Y and see if the coordinate of the touch is inside your C View and then do something with it when the touches end and during the touches dragged.

Comment: Cool! Using UIControlEventTouchDragOutside for the C view works. For your second approach, I have to override the hitTest:withEvent: of the root view A to capture the touch event. Am I correct?